# Why is my picture blinking with my timer

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a text box that that ticks every one second. I had a picture on my form with it and it all worked fine, I decided to change the picture so added a new picture to the form and the picture now blinks every second with the time and can not work out why this is suddenly happening, or how to stop it.

Help

Comment: Please provide adequate information to replicate the problem (at least the name of the picture controls, if they're bound or unbound, and the code behind `Form_Timer`)

Comment: Very strange - I closed access, reopened it and it has fixed itself. Odd

Comment: That's ok, try to do a bit more testing next time, and since the error fixed itself, you better close this question too

Answer (score 0):

Nice to hear that the issue got resolved. However standard procedure to address this issue is to have " application.echo = false" at the beginning of timer event call and "application.echo= true" before the end sub of timer event.